# Various transformation in Homogeneous Coordinates

Tags: linear-transformations, homogeneous-spaces

Today, I learned homogeneous coordinates which solve the notation problem of translation. By homogeneous coordinates, I can became to use translation as matrix notation.

Along this knowledge, there were lots of matrix form that show the various transformation.

1. Translation

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&k\\
0&1&h\\
0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

2. Rotation

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
cos\theta&-sin\theta&0\\
sin\theta&cos\theta&0\\
0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

3. Scalar Multiplication

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
s&0&0\\
0&t&0\\
0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

ETC....

What I'm curious is above matrices are obtained by how? Is it just computation or other proof?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, since you know that homogeneous coordinates solve the problem of translation, you already have seen a proof that the matrix you have given does the job [If not, you should directly compute what this matrix does to $(x,y,1)$; it is a quick and illuminating exercise].

The other two matrices were obtained by just taking the ordinary rotation/scaling matrix, putting it in the upper-left corner, and then putting a $1$ in the lower-right. They clearly do what they say they do, because they do it to the first two coordinates, and leave the third ("homogenizing") coordinate unchanged.

For instance, starting with $(x,y)$ and converting to $(x,y,1)$, and applying the matrix, you compute that the algebraic mess you get is just $(R_x, R_y, 1)$, where $R_x$ and $R_y$ are just the coordinates of the point $(x,y)$ after it has been rotated through some angle. But $(R_x,R_y,1)$ is clearly the conversion of $(R_x,R_y)$, as desired.